# Hubspot -> Zapier -> Google Sheets

Tags: automation, reporting, zapier, hubspot

Trying to work out a zap and need some assistance..
I'm wanting to use the zapier scheduler, and at a time chosen, export contacts in a hubspot list to a google sheet..

effectively, exporting a list to a google sheet, but only processing daily.

i can only seem to do it, running a scheduler then when a new hubspot contact is created...

any thoughts?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Do you have HubSpot Professional or Enterprise (Marketing, Sales, Service or Operations)?

If you have, you can do that in two ways:

1. Using [Google Sheets](https://app.hubspot.com/ecosystem/8940683/marketplace/apps/marketing/data-management/google-sheets-228553) app from HubSpot's Marketplace and HubSpot's Workflows (HubSpot Professional required).
2. Sending a webhook to [Zapier](https://zapier.com/apps/webhook/integrations) and then doing the other Zapier automation (HubSpot Enterprise required).

Personally, I would recommend the first one. With HubSpot's Workflows, you can set timers and delays to do that just once per day.

If you don't have HubSpot Professional or Enterprise to use Workflows, I would recommend setting a trigger at Zapier. Can be anything you desire, like when Contact ID is known or something like that - in this case, Zapier will be triggered just after the contact has been created.

Comment: Is there any way to do it the other way round? From Sheets to Hubspot.